# Does if with ifelse ,ifelse needs to have at least one else statement

Tags: javascript

```
if ()
{}else if (){}
else if (){}
else if (){}
else{}
```

Do we need to have at least one  `else {}`?

Comment: no. and this is not jquery, just javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an else. If your conditions fail, no code will be executed without the else.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, an `else` block is not required.

The following is perfectly valid:

```
if (....) {
}
else if (...) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. Neither is it required when only using an if statement. Your also asking if it needs at least one else statement. The maximum is 1 else statement. You can not have `if(){}else{}else{}` (Wouldn't make sense either :P)